# Spring xml config equivalent to @Order

Tags: java, spring

Given the following Java class

```
@Order(12)
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    //....

}
```

what is the equivalent in the Spring XML configuration? I couldn't find anything matching the `@Order` annotation for the XML based configuration:

```
<bean class="MyComponent" />
```

Comment: Ordered https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to be "ordered, I get: ``org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 60 in XML document from class path resource [component-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 60; columnNumber: 88; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'ordered' is not allowed to appear in element 'bean'.``

Comment: If you are not using annotations, then you need to implement Ordered interface, but that binds your class with spring api.

Comment: Ok, thats what you meant. Hmm kind of annoying if there is no alternative solution :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring you have 2 choices:

- annotation
- interface implementation

In your case you will have to go with the second option.

Your class needs to implement [Ordered](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html), but this will bind your class with spring API. It's same when using annotation over class.

But if you are using configuration classes, instead of xml config, then you can have plain java beans, and keep all Spring API in configurations.
Example:

```
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Order(12)
    public ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService() {
        return Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }
```

Configuration classes give you the option to separate Spring API(annotations) from your beans.

Comment: Ha, this is actually a pretty good idea. You also illustrate my specific issue very well in your example: ``ScheduledExecutorService`` is not under my control, so I can not implement the ``Ordered`` interface nor can I annotate it directly using ``@Order``. By using java configuration I can still manage the class in my spring context and have it ordered when using eg ``@Autowired`` list injection!